# Python - How to get the first row of each list?

Tags: python, list, reshape

I need to get each row of a list and make a new list. Let me explain.

I have this:

```
data = [[204.0, u'stock'], [204.0, u'stock']]
```

I need to transform in this:

```
column1 = [204.0, 204.0]
colunm2 = [u'stock', u'stock']
```

Any clues on how can this be done?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> data = [[204.0, u'stock'], [204.0, u'stock']]
>>> zip(*data)
[(204.0, 204.0), (u'stock', u'stock')]
>>> column1, column2 = zip(*data)
>>> column1
(204.0, 204.0)
>>> column2
(u'stock', u'stock')
```

Or, [`izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> column1, column2 = izip(*data)
>>> column1
(204.0, 204.0)
>>> column2
(u'stock', u'stock')
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple list comprehension will do the trick.

```
data = [[204.0, u'stock'], [204.0, u'stock']]

column1 = [i[0] for i in data]
column2 = [i[1] for i in data]

>>> column1
 [204.0, 204.0]
>>> column2
 ['stock', 'stock']
```

Answer (score 0):

may be , in one line

```
>>> data = [[204.0, u'stock'], [204.0, u'stock']]
>>> columns = [ [d[k] for d in data] for k in range(2)]
[[204.0, 204.0], ['stock', 'stock']]
>>> columns[0]
[204.0, 204.0]
```

and if the size of variable can change you can do this :

```
columns = [ [d[k] for d in data] for k in range(max(map(len,data)))]
```